"That is only one of several reasons he buys the brand." — Why is this correct? I think we must say "THE several reasons he buys the brand"
I found this example in one of the answers on ell.stackexchange.com:
(1a) He chooses Jif® Peanut Butter because he likes the name. But that is only one of several reasons he buys the brand.
It surprised me very much because I think since we have the clarifying relative clause "he buys the brand", we must use "the" before "several reasons":
(1b) He chooses Jif® Peanut Butter because he likes the name. But that is only one of the several reasons he buys the brand.
So why is the absence of "the" in (1a) correct?
Also what's the difference between (1a) and (1b)?

What if we remove "several":
(2a) He chooses Jif® Peanut Butter because he likes the name. But that is only one of reasons he buys the brand.
(2b) He chooses Jif® Peanut Butter because he likes the name. But that is only one of the reasons he buys the brand.
In this case, does (2a) still remain correct?

This is the same as the car question: one of two brands, one of several brands.

Isn't several a determiner?

@TimR No, it can be both a determiner and a modifier and a fused head.

Why do you say several is not a determiner there?

one of several is very well-attested and is preferred to one of the several.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one+of+several%2Cone+of+the+several&year_start=1800&year_end=2022&corpus=en&smoothing=3

Why do you think the clause he buys the brand would have anything to do with the putative need for the definite article "the several reasons"?


What if we remove "several"? does (2a) still remain correct?

That is interesting. It seems that this phrase "one of __ reasons" requires a determiner.  "one of reasons" is wrong, but "one of many reasons", "one of several reasons", "one of the reasons" are all acceptable. Wiktionary categorizes several as a determiner, so it fits the puzzle.

why is the absence of "the" in (1a) correct?

Several can be a determiner. If there's no requirement to have multiple determiners, one is enough. Is "the" needed here? No.

what's the difference between (1a) and (1b)?

(1b) Let's say that a fixed, determined, known list of reasons had been mentioned earlier. Then we can refer back to that list with "the".
(1a). Let's say there are a number of reasons, but we haven't discussed them yet, and they are somewhat unknown or random.  This corresponds to the article "a" in the singular.  "A car".  That means "a car we haven't seen yet", or even "any car", etc.  So it is with these "reasons".
All of this is backwards rationalization as a native speaker, because "the" simply sounds wrong. Then I try to invent logical justifications to defend the position.

"The sun, which is one of (the) trillions of stars in the universe, provides us with heat and light." — According to this link, we can use "one of trillions of stars" without "the". That is, in this case, "trillions" is the noun going after "one of" but has no determiner. Why does this sentence contradict your rule (which says a determiner after "one of" is compulsory) ? Thanks.

We can't say "The sun, which is one of _ stars..." Something is missing, a determiner. I found this on the internet: "Numbers are one kind of determiner." "The sun, which is one of trillions of stars". OK. That includes a number, doesn't it?

Numbers are not always a kind of determiner. CGEL, p. 351: 1) "hundreds" in "hundreds of voters" is a noun functioning as a head; 2) "three hundred" in "three hundred voters" is two determinatives functioning as a determiner; 3) "three hundred" in "three hundred of these voters" is two determinatives functioning as a fused determiner-head. Conclusion: "trillions" in "trillions of stars" is a head noun, that is, it does not function as a determiner or a determiner-head.

I did not phrase it as a "compulsory rule", but wrote "that is interesting. It seems to be the case..."  Anyway, consider the following. All of these are acceptable: one of (several reasons), one of (many reasons), one of (hundreds of reasons).  You can see how those are analogous choices.  I think numbers are unusual and complicated since  "trillions" by itself sounds like something is missing, you must imply or include more.  trillions (of what?).    It's like "several".   Several of what?
